# SQL actualizar campo F con fecha del primer registro que contenga el campo P > 0

Tags: sql, update

Necesito actualizar campo FechaB con el valor del campo FechaA del primer registro que contenga el campo P > 0

ej:

```
--------------------------------
 FechaA  | FechaB | Nombre | P |
--------------------------------
20170506 |        | Juan   |-1 |
20160212 |        | Fer    | 9 | 
20190506 |        | Vale   |-1 |
20190806 |        | Vivi   |-1 |
20190506 |        | Rosa   |-1 |
20180102 |        | Juan   | 2 |
20190506 |        | Vivi   | 1 |
20190506 |        | Juan   | 6 |
20190605 |        | Vivi   | 6 |
```

Y necesito actualizar el campo  FechaB con la el contenido de la FachaA del promer registro que P sea > 0, y me deberia quedar asi!

```
--------------------------------
 FechaA  | FechaB | Nombre | P |
--------------------------------
20170506 |20180102| Juan   |-1 |
20180102 |20180102| Fer    | 9 | 
20190506 |        | Vale   |-1 |
20190806 |20190506| Vivi   |-1 |
20190506 |        | Rosa   |-1 |
20180102 |20180102| Juan   | 2 |
20190506 |20190506| Vivi   | 1 |
20190506 |20180102| Juan   | 6 |
20190605 |20190506| Vivi   | 6 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se adjunta script

```
DROP TABLE Prueba

CREATE TABLE Prueba (
    FechaA DATE NOT NULL,
    FechaB DATE NULL,
    Nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    P INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Prueba VALUES ('20170506', NULL, 'Juan', -1)
INSERT INTO Prueba VALUES ('20180102', NULL, 'Fer', 9)
INSERT INTO Prueba VALUES ('20190506', NULL, 'Vale', -1)
INSERT INTO Prueba VALUES ('20190806', NULL, 'Vivi', -1)
INSERT INTO Prueba VALUES ('20190506', NULL, 'Rosa', -1)
INSERT INTO Prueba VALUES ('20180102', NULL, 'Juan', 2)
INSERT INTO Prueba VALUES ('20190506', NULL, 'Vivi', 1)
INSERT INTO Prueba VALUES ('20190506', NULL, 'Juan', 6)
INSERT INTO Prueba VALUES ('20190605', NULL, 'Vivi', 6)

SELECT * FROM Prueba A

UPDATE A
SET A.FechaB = B.FechaA
FROM
    Prueba A INNER JOIN
    (   SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT
                FechaA,
                FechaB,
                Nombre,
                P,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Nombre ORDER BY Nombre, P ASC) AS ROWORDER
            FROM Prueba
            WHERE P > 0
        ) TEMP
        WHERE ROWORDER = 1
    ) B
    ON A.Nombre = B.Nombre

SELECT * FROM Prueba A
```

El secreto esta en **ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Nombre ORDER BY Nombre, P ASC) AS ROWORDER**, Agrupta y hace un incrementable entre cada grupo, del cual luego solo seleccionamos el primero.

Este es el resultado que obtengo luego de la modificación

```
FechaA      FechaB      Nombre  P
2017-05-06  2018-01-02  Juan    -1
2018-01-02  2018-01-02  Fer      9
2019-05-06  NULL        Vale    -1
2019-08-06  2019-05-06  Vivi    -1
2019-05-06  NULL        Rosa    -1
2018-01-02  2018-01-02  Juan     2
2019-05-06  2019-05-06  Vivi     1
2019-05-06  2018-01-02  Juan     6
2019-06-05  2019-05-06  Vivi     6
```

A la espera de tu respuesta.

Comment: me sirvió! Pude resolver el problema.

Comment: Excelente, te agradecería marcar como **respuesta correcta**, para poder ayudar a aquellos que pasen por el mismo problema.

Answer (score 1):

El concepto de "primer" registro siempre está asociado a un determinado orden definido en tu consulta. Las tablas NO tienen un orden natural. Entiendo que tu caso, el orden está estaría dado por la cronología de `FechaA`, si es así, puedes hacer:

```
UPDATE  TuTabla
    SET FechaB = T2.FechaB
    FROM TuTabla T1
    INNER JOIN (select Nombre, Min(FechaA) AS FechaB
            from TuTabla 
            where p > 0
            group by Nombre
        ) T2
        ON T1.Nombre = T2.Nombre
```

Básicamente:

- Buscamos la primer `fechaA` para todos los `Nombre`
- Luego simplemente es actualizar aquellos que tuvieran está fecha